Is it possible to open a socket on a char device in Linux?
I would like to use libpcap on my char device. libpcap establishes a socket connection to its devices. Is there a way to connect my char device via socket?
I already tried to just open the char device with the pcaplib, but it didn't work.

In short: no. Sockets and char devices are different file types.

Depends, some of them are supported by socat.
